# Which is the best CMS for multi subdomains handling

Tags: content-management-system, open-source, subdomain

I am looking for a free CMS that would handle subdomains very well.

Say I want to create a website called cars.com and I want to have multiple blogs/wikis/forums... about each brand :
 - ford.cars.com
 - toyota.cars.com
 - bmw.cars.com

Which CMS should I use to create this ?

---

My first guess was [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/start), does it stand the comparison with drupal when it comes to collaborative work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/)'s built-in [multi-site](http://drupal.org/node/43816) functionality provides a lot of flexibility for running separate sites out-of-the-box. The add-on [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) provides even more flexibility by allowing you to share content, users, and configuration between the sites.